# How to design a form that mostly is read-only, but sometimes editable?

Tags: forms, input-fields

Often in database-centric application I need to design a view for records e.g. something like:

```
Name: __________
Phone Nr: _________
Website: ______
Email: __________@________
Location: ____________
Address: ______________
         ______________
Post code: ________
```

These views are mostly read-only, but sometimes the user needs to edit them.

What is a good way to show them in read-only mode? and what is a good way to switch to editable mode? What is the drawbacks with showing the fields in read-only mode as "disabled" input fields?

E.g. usually I design these views as forms, where the fields are disabled, and I have a "Edit" button that change all fields to enabled. But showing the fields as labels may be an alternative for read-only mode.

But here on StackOverflow, the profile pages are shown as labels/text and switched to forms when the user clicks "edit".

Comment: I think you answered it on the last line here, "on StackOverflow, the profile pages are shown as labels/text and switched to forms when the user clicks "edit"."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Showing the normal read-only view as a bunch of disabled form input elements will be visually ugly and contextually confusing; you're making it look like a form that you can't use, and it may not be readily apparent why it's not editable (because it's not a form yet!). You're violating good affordance by making things look like editable forms when they really aren't (in this view). Instead use plain text/lables and present it neatly like it's a piece of paper.

An edit button is a great way to toggle the view and make it clear why this view is read only. The simplest way would be to make the edit button switch to a different page that displays an editable input form.

As you've hit upon with your SE example, the alternative is to make the view only view *look* like text, but automatically change into a standard form appearance once you hit the edit button.

In a web app you can give this effect by using disabled form elements in your read only view and then **style away the input boxes**, the "greyed out" effect, ect, so you can easily hide the fact that you're using form elements until you click the edit button, when voilà, it's a form with a standard appearance, aiding affordance in both states.